# json-path: Filter on child of an array within another array

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, predicate, jsonpath

I have a JSONArray within a JSONArray, I want to apply JSONPath expression on this in such a way that i get JSONObject or JSONArray as a result when a condition is satsified on the inner JSONArray.

Eg:

```
{
  "A": [
    {
      "B": [
        {
          "id": 1
        },
        {
          "id": 2
        },
        {
          "id": 3
        }
      ],
      "C": {
        "id": 10,
        "name": "PQR"
      },
      "id": 25,
      "name": "XYZ"
    },
    {
      "B": [
        {
          "id": 4
        },
        {
          "id": 5
        },
        {
          "id": 6
        }
      ],
      "C": {
        "id": 15,
        "name": "PQR"
      },
      "id": 20,
      "name": "XYZ"
    }
  ]
}
```

if i want all elements of A where `C.id = 10`, I would use: `$.A[?(@.C.id == 10)]`

Now, What predicate is to be used to obtain all the objects within A, where `B.id = 1`? Note: B is an array of JSON objects.

Answer (score 1):

I had success with `$.A[?(@.B[?(@.id == 1)])]`

but only when using Scala's Gatling implementation:
http://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/

The Jayway implementation seems to totally ignore the inner filter and according to an [issue](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath/issues/287) on their GitHub, that's a bug.

Comment: You're right, With Gatling it did work for me. But i am using the Jayway library, Are you sure its a limitation?

Comment: @VishalMahuli updated the answer, it looks like a bug.